# I can't check in for tomorrow's flight without a Canada transit visa

Tags: canada, transit-visas, air-canada, yyz

I am an Indian citizen, traveling to India tomorrow from the USA. I have a valid US work visa. My flight is United (operated by Air Canada), with a connection at Toronto with 1 hour layover. I was trying to check in for my flight, but I cannot check in as I do not have a transit visa!

I think I am screwed, but if I apply online is there any chance of getting it by tomorrow noon?

Answer (score 4):

The [processing times](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html) for Canadian temporary resident visas (of which the transit visa is one type) applied in the USA is currently 19 days. It's very unlikely that you would be able to receive this visa before tomorrow.

You should contact your ticketing carrier immediately to change your flight itinerary to transit through another country.

Comment: Thank you. I thought as much. This is unbelievable, to have to go through all this hassle just for a 1 hour layover.

Comment: Do you know if eTA is a better option? The website says that it is processed in minutes apparently. It will still be cheaper than changing the flight tickets which would be $500 or so :(

Comment: @Ufder You can't use the eTA unless you are a _permanent_ resident of the USA (with a green card).

Comment: Gotcha. So I am totally stuck. Well, thanks for the help. I guess I have no one else but myself to blame.

Comment: @Ufder It's always a good idea to check any possible visa requirements before booking tickets, so that you can either avoid these situations, or have enough time to obtain any transit visas you might need. If United is your ticketing carrier they should be able to route you so that you transit through a Schengen area country, in this case you would not need a transit visa. Of course changing the tickets may be expensive, but it probably will be less expensive than completely new tickets.

Comment: Yeah, the original ticket was about 1000. I can get a change for the same fare, but the change fee is $250. Its not too bad, but still that's a lot of money. Thank you for your help. Hope this helps someone in the future.